# Signal and alarm function

Tags: c, signals, alarm

I require some assistance or advice in a C programming task that I received...
The task is that with the `alarm(sec)` a signal `SIGALRM` needs to be called.
I have to increase a long int number in 1 second and print out on the screen how many times the number was increased in that time. I suspect that it will have to go with the `alarm(1);` 
I have the loop to increase the number ... bit have absolutely no idea on how to stop it after 1 second especially with the `signal(SIGALRM,xxx)`
Shall I paste in the code that I have ?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <signal.h> 

int loop_function() { 
    int counter = 1; 
    long int n = 1; 
    while(n!=0) { 
        ++counter; 
        n++; 
        printf("%d: %d\n",counter,n); 
    } 
} 

int main() { 
   loop_function();
}
```

Comment: Ok - :)
Here's what I made up ... 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int loop_function(){
int counter = 1;
long int n = 1;
while(n!=0){
++counter;
n++;
printf("%d: %d\n",counter,n);
}
}

int main()
{
loop_function();
//I'm stuck now ... 

}

Comment: why it looks so strange ?

Comment: @slavmir Edit your answer with the code, and start each line with four spaces :)

Comment: I think Kai edited the code ... Thank you 
Sorry I'm totally new here ..

Comment: @slavmir can you post your code for signal handler.

Comment: @Pawan that's the thing I'm missing and to be honest ... I don't have a clue on how to set this ...    where to put the alarm() function

Comment: @slavmir I posted the answer to you query. But I strongly sugesst that you can only learn by making your hands dirty. Doesn't matter, what you try but try something, and then see what the result rather than relying on something/someone else. At last, the choice is yours :)

Comment: @Pawan - thank you very much. To be honest I was struggling with this since last Wednesday ...      I still don't understand this fully.
But thanks a lot - I'll be looking into this

Comment: @slavmir, please upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: @Pawan - done that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this is what you are looking for.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void sigalrm_handler(int);
int loop_function();

static int counter = 1;
static long int n = 1;

int main()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, sigalrm_handler);
    //This will set the alarm for the first time.
    //Subsequent alarms will be set from sigalrm_handler() function
    alarm(1);

    printf("Inside main\n");

    while(1)
    {
        loop_function();
    }
    return(0);
}

void sigalrm_handler(int sig)
{
    printf("inside alarm signal handler\n");
    printf("%d: %d\n",counter,n);
    //exit(1);
    alarm(1);
}

int loop_function()
{
        ++counter;
        n++;
}
```